# classpath not working - java lang ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, classpath

I have a jar called GameClient.jar which has a main method. And I have a json.jar which does contain an org/json/JSONException.class

Both of these are in the dist folder.

I run the following 
`java -classpath dist/json.jar -jar dist/gameclient.jar`

Not really sure why I still get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
```

I am on Windows XP and Java 1.7. I get the same error with or without the classpath option.

Comment: Is directory "dist" relative to the current working directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the `java` documentation:

> -jar
>
> Execute a program encapsulated in a JAR file. The first argument is the name of a JAR file
>          instead of a startup class name. In order for this option to work, the manifest of the JAR
>          file must contain a line of the form Main-Class: classname. Here, classname identifies the
>          class having the public static void main(String[] args) method that serves as your appli-
>          cation's starting point. See the jar(1) and the Jar trail of the Java Tutorial @
>          http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jar for information about working with Jar files
>          and Jar-file manifests.
>
> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user
>          class path settings are ignored.

So your `gameclient.jar` must include all of the user classes that you need. The `classpath` setting is ignored. Just create the `gameclient.jar` to include the classes in `json.jar`.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than supplying the classpath as a command line argument you can add a classpath entry to your `GameClient` `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Class-Path: dist/json.jar
```

See [Including a Class-Path In Your MANIFEST.MF](https://blogs.oracle.com/olaf/entry/jdev_including_a_classpath_in)